# Programmatically Set Column Options in TFS 2018.2

Tags: rest, tfs

We are creating team projects with the rest API and would like to automate the configuration the column options like in the [UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/backlogs/set-column-options?view=tfs-2018). We want to configure the column and column order for all backlogs.

I can get the backlogConfiguration in [TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/work/backlog-configuration?view=tfs-2018) and [VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/work/backlogconfiguration/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) using the existing APIs but it does not look like there is a POST, PATCH or PUT method to update the backlogConfiguration. Is there any other way to programmatically set these values?

We are running TFS 2018 Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't the API to update/change the Column Options. We cannot achieve that programmatically.